# Extract correct number of matching rows from two tables in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem for extracting the correct number of rows from my table1 wich are matching with my table2.

Explanation :

My first table "table1" is a list of Sample (for example):

```
    Patient ID    Visit        Typology       Date               Box
    01            V1           Plasma       11-10-2012            1
    01            V1           Plasma       11-10-2012            2
    01            V1           Plasma       11-10-2012            3
    01            V1           Urine        11-10-2012            4 
    01            V1           Urine        11-10-2012            5
    01            V1           Urine        11-10-2012            6
```

My second table "table2" contains sample I want to extract :

```
    Patient ID    Visit        Typology       Date              
    01            V1           Plasma       11-10-2012            
    01            V1           Plasma       11-10-2012            
    01            V1           Plasma       11-10-2012            
    01            V1           Urine        11-10-2012            
    01            V1           Urine        11-10-2012
```

So I want to extract the Box information from the table "table1" for samples which are matching.
But the problem is that rows can match but I don't want all of it : I want only the firsts matching rows

For example I wanted to extract the three sample of Plasma but only two of Urine.

With a JOIN on the different rows I have all the mathing rows but I don't want the third 'Urine'

Is there somebody to help me with this trouble ?

Comment: I think this bb design is bad. You are storing redundand data. If not, then you need to assign a foreign key to the table2, or make a relation table.

Comment: It is not redundant data, it is the same type of sample but store in another tube, so it's another sample. There are of course unique id on this samples. Make a relation table what does it mean ?